# Virtual Machine optimizers

Tags: virtual-machine, performance, disk-space

I have read a discussion about [musthave Windows software](https://superuser.com/questions/1241/must-have-windows-software). User esabine addend a link to [Scott Hanselman's tools list](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ScottHanselmans2007UltimateDeveloperAndPowerUsersToolListForWindows.aspx). One of the tools Scott was writing about was an optimizer tool for VM’s. - Invirtus VM Optimizer for 70 USD. However, Invirtus is not in the market anymore, and was acquired by Quest and Vizioncore. The prices went up 4 times (to about 300 USD).

Does anyone knows good VM optimizer tool, that will work with VMWare Workstation?

Comment: +1 for good question. Invirtus VM Optimizer was great for optimizing VM footprint - it would do many things that out-of-the-box tools didn't do, like nuke all the Windows help files (who needs those in a barebones VM?)  Since I haven't been able to use it in forever, I'm forgetting some of the other nice features that it used to have. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VMware does have [built in tools for shrinking Virtual Disks](http://pubs.vmware.com/ws6_ace2/ws/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ws&file=ws_disk_shrink.html).

And you can also [use the VMware Virtual Disk Manager to do this](http://pubs.vmware.com/ws6_ace2/ws/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ws&file=ws_disk_manager_examples.html).

Answer (score 3):

A lot of supposed optimizers just make it easier to remove unnecessary software/services from Windows--items that can be removed manually (for free) by the user.

I agree with Dave Webb's suggestion for using VMWare's built-in tools.  In addition, I keep a bare-bones image (whether it's XP, Vista, or Windows 7) with as much of the bloat uninstalled/disabled.  I'll use the bare-bones image as a base for subsequent clones.

The biggest optimization IMHO is ensuring that your VM isn't fragmented.

Comment: I do not grok the last part. Why would that matter enough to worry for the guest. (I understand why you do not want the vmdk on the host to be fragmented).